# using textscan to read badly formatted CSV file in Octave

Tags: csv, octave, textscan

I am trying to read a CSV file in Octave with `textscan` and the CSV file isn't always correctly formatted. The following mcve should illustrate the issue:

Let's say the file is as follows:

```
12/01/2020,12,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,0
11/01/2020,11,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,0
10/01/2020,10,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,0
09/01/2020,9,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,0
08/01/2020,8,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,0
07/01/2020,7,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,
06/01/2020,6,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,
05/01/2020,5,1,2020,0,0,Russia,RU,RUS,145872260,Europe,
```

You will notice that the final 0 is missing in the last 3 lines. Obviously, I can go in and manually edit the CSV files in Notepad++ or similar, but we're talking several tens of thousands of lines to go through and I just feel there must be a better solution.

My code would be something like this (note that I have tried using `%*f` for the last element to tell Octave to skip it but that doesn't seem to work):

```
fname = 'mcve.csv'; % the above file
fid = fopen(fname);
csv_data = textscan(fid,'%s %d %d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d %s %*f','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
```

If you then look at `csv_data`, you will see that the dates are not correct (the rest of the data looks OK):

```
>> csv_data{1}
ans =
{
  [1,1] = 12/01/2020
  [2,1] = 11/01/2020
  [3,1] = 09/01/2020
  [4,1] = 08/01/2020
  [5,1] = 07/01/2020
  [6,1] = /01/2020
  [7,1] = /01/2020
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this or what else to try other than the `%*f` I already tried?

Comment: is the only variation you need to accommodate the presence or lack of a trailing 0?  Notepad++ with an intelligent find/replace might be much faster anyway.  Replace "Europe," with "Europe,0", then replace all ",00" with ",0".  other variations may be just as fast.

Comment: haven't tried this, but another approach might be to remove the delimiter statement, add the commas into the format string, and have it include the ',0' in the %s with the 'Europe'.  parse and correct the missing 0 separately after the data is read.

Comment: Yes, the missing trailing 0 is the only thing I am trying to accomodate. The `csv2cell` option suggested in the answer seems to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv2cell` from the `io` package.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I had to rearange some of the downstream code because the resulting cell from `csv2cell` is structured differently from the one from `textscan`, but essentially it worked.

Comment: @am304 glad to hear it. Honestly, I feel like I give this answer to a variant of the textscan question in the comments every other week. Textscan is horrible. I think I might just start linking to this answer instead from now on. :)