# Looking for a method to import .txt file containing both strings& numbers in Octave

Tags: import, octave, importdata

Hope you're doing well,

I've been assigned a task to make plotting data easier for the lab I work in. I am trying to import a .txt file with the following format into Octave:
[Datafile labdata1.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C6oC.png)

It looks to me like the data file has 2 header lines, 9 number columns following by 1 string column , one more number column and 1 more string column.

In my past work I used importdata() to accomplish this. My import trial below.

```
f1 = 'labdata1.txt'
delimiterIn = "\t";
headerLinesIn = 3;
Fdata_1 = importdata(f1,delimiterIn,headerLinesIn)
```

But this now throws me an error, as follows:

```
>> ImportTrial
f1 = labdata1.txt
error: missing_idx(13): out of bound 12 (dimensions are 1x12)
error: called from
    importdata>importdata_ascii at line 320 column 21
    importdata at line 133 column 40
    ImportTrial at line 8 column 9
```

Anyone know what's going on here? Help is much appreciated!

Best regards, Canter

Trial is already explained above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885690/4183191

Comment: PS. If your file is actually 'tab-delimited', you should specify tab as the delimiter (i.e. '\t''). If it's space delimited, this will work but you may have to capture the two parts of the date separately. Before parsing with csv2cell, get the first line separately, since that has a different format, and specify that csv2cell should start from the second line; if it's space delimited you may have to introduce another header for the 'time' part of the date.

Comment: what version of Octave and on what Operating System?

Comment: so the error you're getting is interesting. Could you please attach an actual sample data file to the question?  I recreated one manually from your image, and your textscan command reads it in without error on Octave 8.4.0 and a recent build of 9.0.1 (on Windows, but I tried on files with both windows and linux line endings, which I thought might have been the culprit)